# How can you import an Excel file with a dropdown list column into a Sharepoint list as a Choice column?

Tags: excel, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list

I followed the directions on the following site

[How to add a drop down list to an Excel cell](https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/how-to-add-a-drop-down-list-to-an-excel-cell/)

and created an Excel spreadsheet with a dropdown list column. When I export this sheet to Sharepoint, that column is coming across as a Single line of Text.

How can I have it come across as a column of type Choice(menu to choose from) with each choice prepopulated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a SharePoint list via an Excel file does not create choice columns from dropdown (data validation) columns.  SharePointMaven has a comparison of different approaches here: 
https://sharepointmaven.com/3-ways-import-excel-sharepoint/

None of them convert the data validation data to a choice column.

You will need to edit the list columns and change their definitions manually.

Don't shoot the messenger.

Comment: I contacted Microsoft about having this feature as a future enhancement. I also added it to uservoice as an idea https://office365.uservoice.com/forums/264636-general/suggestions/38526235-implement-exporting-of-excel-dropdown-list-column